# How to get the file name of current style using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, style

I get the name of the current style file using `layer.styleURI()`.  Then, I change the style file using `layer.loadNamedStyle(different_filename)`.

However, when I call `layer.styleURI()` again, it returns the same name as in previous call.  How can I get the file name of the current style in QGIS using Python?

Comment: I tried testing this and it does seem that the `layer.styleURI()` command simply brings the location of the layer (and adds a .qml even if that file doesn't exist) and **not** the style file. Perhaps this hasn't been completely implemented correctly or it's a bug? Hopefully others can advise.

Comment: I can report the same thing. There will always be a .qml even though it does not always exist. I can save a style, and call it, no problem. But using the above command will always return the same thing.

Comment: @wannik I confirm this behavior in QGIS 2.6. Have you contacted [QGIS-devs](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer)? The issue you are reporting here could be addressed directly by them. You could report it opening a new issue [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues), see [Filing an issue](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#filing-an-issue).

Comment: Thank you all for your attention to my question. I tried to report the issue but still cannot do it.

Comment: @wannik I'm elaborating an answer, stay tuned ;)

Comment: @gcarrillo Thank you so much for the answer.  I'm really sorry that I haven't given the bounty score to you.  After the question was identified as a bug, I don't pay much attention to it.  Thinking that there is no way to solve it. Please accept my apology.

Comment: @wannik :/ Yes, I was only 20 minutes late to let you know I was elaborating an answer, and it was too late indeed, since the bounty expired. But don't worry, I hope the solution works for you.

Comment: @wannik I've also answered another question you posted, please check it out. :)

Comment: @gcarrillo Thank you so much for your kind reply.  :) I will check the solution to another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to do what I state in 1. and choose whether you want to go for 2. while the problem is fixed in QGIS.

1. Indeed, there is a problem with those functions, so you can inform QGIS devs about the issue you found by posting in the [QGIS-dev mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer) and/or reporting it in the QGIS bug tracker (see [Filing an issue](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#filing-an-issue)).
2. Implement a workaround.

   Since `layer.styleURI()` is not giving you the updated style, you can use your own functions for keeping track of your styles. For instance, by implementing the following functions, you could get updated styles by calling `styleURI( layer )` and `loadNamedStyle( layer, stylePath )`.

   Just define the functions this way:

   ```
   def loadNamedStyle( layer, stylePath ):
       res = layer.loadNamedStyle( stylePath )
       if res[1]: # Style loaded
           layer.setCustomProperty( "layerStyle", stylePath )
           return True
       return False

   def styleURI( layer ):
       return layer.customProperty( "layerStyle", "" )
   ```

   Once they are defined, you could use them this way:

   ```
   layer = iface.activeLayer()
   styleURI( layer ) # Will print "" (A style file hasn't been set) 
   loadNamedStyle( layer, "/path/to/mystyle.qml") # Prints True if style exists and applies it
   styleURI( layer ) # Will print "/path/to/mystyle.qml" if previous line was True
   ```

   Since I've used custom properties in these functions, the style path will be saved across sessions just by saving your QGIS project.

   You could even write the function definitions in a .py file (say `style_functions.py`) and save it in the same folder as your QGIS project. This way, you would just need to write:

   ```
   from style_functions import *
   ```

   in the QGIS Python console to have the functions ready to be used.

Comment: Very nicely done!